# Evento click dentro de un loop For

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un color picker. Cada vez que hago click en una muestra de color, se actualiza en color y nombre del color en otro `div`. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var indicadorColor = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color');
var indicadorMensaje = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color-mensaje');
var color = document.getElementsByClassName('color-paleta');

function seleccionarColor(){      
  for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){
    color[i].addEventListener('click', mostrarColor)
  }

  function mostrarColor(){
    indicadorColor.setAttribute('backgroundColor',color[i].style.backgroundColor);
    indicadorMensaje.innerText = color[i].style.backgroundColor;
  }
}
seleccionarColor();
```

Pero me devuelve undefined para `color[i]`, no se porque :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que utilizar this en vez de `color[i]`:

```
var indicadorColor = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color');
var indicadorMensaje = document.getElementById('indicador-de-color-mensaje');
var color = document.getElementsByClassName('color-paleta');

function mostrarColor(){
  indicadorColor.setAttribute('backgroundColor',this.style.backgroundColor);
  indicadorMensaje.innerText = this.style.backgroundColor;
}

function seleccionarColor(){
  for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){
    color[i].addEventListener('click', mostrarColor)
  }
}

seleccionarColor();
```